# Bluetooth device connection lost after a second

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, serial

With the Raspberry Pi 3B i was able to succesfully pair and connect a Barcodescanner (OPN2006). For this, I used the following code:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[NEW] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 OPN2006_18D4
[bluetooth]# pair 38:89:DC:00:18:D4
Attempting to pait with 38:89:DC:00:18:D4
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Connected: yes
...
Pairing successful
```

I bought a Raspberry Pi 4 and run the same code. Everything works the same, but one second after

```
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Connected: yes
```

there appears:

```
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Connected: no
```

and Pairing successful doesn't show up. Has anyone an idea why it works on the Pi 3B, but not on the Pi4?

`service bluetooth status`, `bluetoothctl show` give the same output for both, `dpkg -l | grep blue` gives the following Output for the Raspberry PI 3B:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg -l | grep blue
ii  bluetooth                            5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               all          Bluetooth support (metapackage)
ii  bluez                                5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-firmware                       1.2-4+rpt8                          all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  bluez-obexd                          5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                          2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2            armhf        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  pi-bluetooth                         0.1.15                              all          Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth
```

And for the Raspberry Pi 4:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg -l | grep blue
ii  blueman                              2.0.8-1+deb10u1                     armhf        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                            5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               all          Bluetooth support (metapackage)
ii  bluez                                5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-firmware                       1.2-4+rpt8                          all          Firmware for Bluetooth devices
ii  bluez-hcidump                        5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets
ii  bluez-obexd                          5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                          2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2            armhf        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  libbluetooth3:armhf                  5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2               armhf        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  lxplug-bluetooth                     0.21                                armhf        Bluetooth plugin for lxpanel
ii  pi-bluetooth                         0.1.15                              all          Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth          12.2-4+deb10u1+rpi3                 armhf        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

So all the bluetooth packages from the Raspberry Pi 3B are installed on the Pi 4, even some more. Could the additional ones be a problem?

There is something more to add. I have two SD Cards, both work on the Raspberry Pi 3B like this:

```
[NEW] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 OPN2006_18D4
[bluetooth]# pair 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 
Attempting to pair with 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Connected: yes 
Request confirmation [agent] Confirm passkey 579553 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
```

And both have the pairing problem on the Raspberry Pi 4 like this:

```
[NEW] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 OPN2006_18D4
[bluetooth]# pair 38:89:DC:00:18:D4
Attempting to pair with 38:89:DC:00:18:D4
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Connected: yes
Request confirmation [agent] Confirm passkey 148315 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device 38:89:DC:00:18:D4 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 38:89:DC:00:18:D4
Attempting to connect to 38:89:DC:00:18:D4
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

So there is no `Pairing successful` with the Pi 4.

Comment: You might need to share some more debug information. For example are there different messages from `service bluetooth status`, `bluetoothctl show`, `dpkg -l | grep blue`, or `journalctl -u bluetooth`? If they look the same between the two machines then to see the low-level Bluetooth information, use `sudo btmon` in a different terminal while you run your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ukBaz . I tried the different commands and added the information in the answer below.

Comment: You posted the added info as an answer. Please add it to the question above.

Comment: Is there anything in the following thread that helps you? https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth/issues/8

Comment: It actually did @ukBaz , thank you so much! I tried it several times and came to the following fact: it only works, if I type `systemctl restart bluetooth`, after a reboot or power interruption. I got the same mistake when i tried to pair without using this command after a restart.